# How to check if a category has a parent WooComerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, categories

I have this code but not working. I'm trying to check if the category has a parent but always this code return then category does not have a parent.

```
$cat_id = $wp_query->get_queried_object()->term_id;
echo $cat_id;

function category_has_parent($cat_id)
{
    $category = get_category($cat_id);
    if ($category->parent > 0) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

if (category_has_parent($cat_id)) {
    echo 'have parent ';
}else{
    echo 'does not have a parent';
}
```